# Use VBA to Search Excel and Export Certain Data

Tags: vba, excel

So I have now changed the macro below to this and am getting a

> Runtime 1004 error at

```
ActiveSheet.Name = ShipperName
```

Code:

```
Sub CopyShipperToNewSheet()

Dim LR As Long
Dim ShipperName As String

' Last row of your data
LR = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop Name range ( Column U)
For i = 2 To Range("U" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ShipperName = Cells(i, 21)

    ' Use filter
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    ' field =4 (column D----Shippers Name)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ShipperName

    ' Copy visible cell
    [A1].CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' Paste to new sheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveSheet.Name = ShipperName

    ' Go back sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Name = ShipperName` --> runtime 1004 error.Yes! Read error message carefully you will find you have the same sheet name already.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I sometimes have a need to export each sheet to its own workbook for when an invoice for a particular location is requested. Any ideas as to the best way to go about this?

Comment: It is easy when it is 1 or 2 locations, but when say, 75, ask it is a bit more tedious.

Comment: Copy worksheet to workbook is another question...

Answer (score 0):

**First get unique shipper name**

The screenshot：

[image]

You can change this macro for yourself:

```
Sub CopyShipperToNewSheet()

Dim LR As Long
Dim ShipperName As String

' Last row of your data
LR = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop Name range ( Column F)
For i = 2 To Range("F" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ShipperName = Cells(i, 6)

    ' Use filter
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    ' field =4 (column D----Name)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ShipperName

    ' Copy visible cell
    [A1].CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' Paste to new sheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveSheet.Name = ShipperName

    ' Go back sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out and let you know how it works. If I get any errors I can't figure out I am sure I will be back haha.